# Kibana - graph with delta between two field of two different document

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, metrics

I use the ELK stack to monitoring many Java services and more precisly I use the logstash input JMX for getting data into Elasticsearch.

In one of them, I get the number of message received by my service since the start of the service. So it's an incremental value and I would like to create a graph with the number of messages received / seconds.

In input data I have this kind of data:

```
  {
      "metric_value_number": 1633157,
      "hostname": "server1",
      "metricsName": "ExchangesCompleted"
  },
  {
      "metric_value_number": 1633811,
      "hostname": "server1",
      "metricsName": "ExchangesCompleted"
  },
  {
      "metric_value_number": 1634512,
      "hostname": "server1",
      "metricsName": "ExchangesCompleted"
  }
```

I would like for each document, calculate the delta between his value and the value of the document before him.

In my exemple I want to do :

```
    1633157 - 0 = 1633157
    1633811 - 1633157 = 654
    1634512 - 1633811 = 701
```

And graph the result of this operation.

I can not find a way to do that. Most of the time people use scripted field in kibana but always do an operation between fields of the SAME document and I want to do this with different document.

It's the same behavior of this post : [Kibana time delta between two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673468/kibana-time-delta-between-two-fields) but my data are in different field

Some one already did this kind of things ?

Best regards,
Clément.

Comment: I have the similar issue where i have to calculate the delta of "start time" from one document to "end time" in other document.
anyone tried this sort of thing?